# cards created dynamically are arranged vertically it should be horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a card dynamically but when I create the cards they  are vertically arranged. I need them to be arranged horizontally.

```js
function _getall() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8888/books1/getall',
    type: 'GET',    
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) {          
      var templateString = '';
      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
       templateString = '<div class="card"><div class="container"> 
        <h4><b>'+item.name+'</b></h4><p>'+item.description+'</p><h4>'
         + item.author+'</h4><h4>' + item.price+'</h4><h4>'
         + item.release_date+'</h4><button class="button" 
           onclick="_deleteBook('+item.id+')">Delete</button>'
         + '<a href="http://localhost:8888/updatebook"><button 
         class="button" onclick="_update('+item.id+')">Update</button></a> 
         </div> 
         </div>'; 
         $('#test').append(templateString);
       })   
     },
     error: function(request, error) {
       alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
     }
   });
```

Comment: Does that code even work at all? It seems like you have several syntax issues.

Comment: If you want `div` elements to appear side by side, use `display: inline-block`

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, you can check their documentation about cards (what they show as example is creating a grid), otherwise as @RoryMcCrossan mentioned you just need to style them appropriately to what you want.

Comment: Let's hope you want the `templateString` to be display in full page, then use `<div class="col-md-12">`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a simple css class for your cards. [Here is an example](https://codepen.io/DanStevens/pen/YJoMGa) of how I'm assuming your templateString will be rendered in the browser. You can see how your cards now stack horizontally.

```
.card {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Taking this a step further, I would consider using a [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) if you want a responsive layout.